# In java, I want to check daemon thread's thread group but it occurs an error

Tags: java, multithreading, daemon, java-threads

I want to check the thread group.
So I made some codes but occurred a nullPointerException Error.

I made two classes, main and daemon thread class.

this is main class.

---

### main code

```
public class ThreadInfoEx {
public static void main(String[] args){
AST ast = new AST();
ast.setName("AST");
ast.setDaemon(true);
ast.start();
    
Map<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> map = Thread.getAllStackTraces();
Set<Thread> threads = map.keySet();
    
for(Thread thread : threads) {
System.out.println("name : " + thread.getName() + ((thread.isDaemon?"daemon":"main")));
System.out.println("\t" + "group name : " + thread.getThreadGroup().getName());
System.out.println();
}
}
}
```

---

and this is AST(daemon class). actually just made an empty class to create daemon thread.

---

### AST code

```
public class AST extends Thread {
@Override
public void run() {
System.out.println("^"); //to check whether works or not          
}
}
```

---

and the error comes with nullpointerException error.
it says the blow main code has an error when it goes through AST (daemon) class.
System.out.println("\t" + "group name : " + thread.getThreadGroup().getName());

AST class is nothing but it is working because I set it up as daemon.

In my knowledge, the error occurs when showing the reference variable which has null. but, the AST class must be in the main thread group because in main class, I coded "ast.setDaemon(true);".
doesn't it mean that now its belong to main class?

but why do i get that error?

Comment: it is pretty simple but I do not really get why nullPointerException occurs

Comment: Try to add default constructor with `super()` call

Comment: I also think, that at the point of calling `Thread.getAllStackTraces()` the thread might have already terminated and is no longer available at this point, or in the for-loop

Comment: Thank you Dominik Loventinsky. This thread is a little bit hard to study. but will not give up. I found out that if AST class does not contain any running codes, it will be created and terminated at the same time. yup, Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo instead of `thread.isDaemon` it should be `thread.isDaemon()` as it is a function not a member variable. After fixing the code when `Thread.getAllStackTraces()` is called and if AST thread is still active the map will contain its object, after that the thread becomes dead and in the api doc it is mentioned that

```
public final ThreadGroup getThreadGroup()
Returns the thread group to which this thread belongs. This 
method returns null if this thread has died (been stopped).
```

reference:-
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getThreadGroup--

So when calling the `getThreadGroup().getName()` method in the for loop when thread object is of AST it is giving you a null pointer exception. Below is the code to recreate this scenario in a more concrete way:-

```
class ThreadInfoEx {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        AST ast = new AST();
        ast.setName("AST");
        ast.setDaemon(true);
        ast.start();

        Map<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> map = Thread.getAllStackTraces();
        Set<Thread> threads = map.keySet();
        ast.join();
        for(Thread thread : threads) {
            System.out.println("name : " + thread.getName() + ((thread.isDaemon()?"daemon":"main")));
            System.out.println("\t" + "group name : " + thread.getThreadGroup().getName());
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}

class AST extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("^"); //to check whether works or not
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I read the document and now I understand why it did not work well. Thank you very much. when AST class is created, at the same time it will be terminated(or be in waiting pool) right? because it does not have any running code.

Comment: AST class is just a structure but when you create an object using `AST ast = new AST();` a new thread is created and it is in new state. To run the thread you call `ast.start()` in the main thread at this point you are saying that this thread can be picked up by the cpu to be executed then the actual code executes which is in run method and after completing it is killed. So what happened was it got picked by cpu and it was in running state at the time when on main thread `Thread.getAllStackTraces()` was called and was in dead state when for loop was executed hence the null pointer exception.